# Where to add events to nodes?

Tags: java, javafx

Can you tell me, where I should declare my event listeners for Nodes, which are added out side of my controller class?

The best way is to explain it with this example:

I have my controller:

```
public class FXMLDocumentController implements Initializable {

    @FXML
    private AnchorPane root;

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
        TestTask test = new TestTask(root);
        Thread th = new Thread(test);
        th.start();
    }    
}
```

And then I have the Task, which is started in the initialize method:

```
public class TestTask extends Task<Void>{

    private AnchorPane root;

    public TestTask(AnchorPane root){
        this.root = root;
    }

    @Override
    protected Void call() throws Exception {
        Button btn = new Button("TestButton");
        Platform.runLater(() -> { root.getChildren().add(btn); });
        return null;
    }
}
```

What I'm doing here? I have a FXML with an AnchorPane as root element. It has the id root. So now I start the Task in which I add one Button to my root node. Now I want to register an action event to the button. My question is now, where can/should I register the listener. Normally I register them in the controller, but here I can't do this because the Button only exists in the Task class. I could register it in the Task class but I think that it not scales good with large applications. The other way would to return the node back, so that I can access it in the controller class, but here I have to check if it is already added (to do this I have to call `task.get()`, which stops my application. So now could you tell me: what is the best way to register the listener for the node?

Comment: But  why don't you create the Button directly in your controller? I don't understand why you need the thread?

Comment: "I have to check if it's already added". Since you create a new button in the `call()` method, it's impossible for it already to have been added.

Comment: That is only an example. Think about somthing like "create a button for every File in an directory". You have to create them dynamicly and sometimes it is not possible in the EDT.

Comment: You retrieve the data in the task and return it, then create the button on the UI thread in the `onSucceeded` handler. There's (almost?) never a reason to create the actual UI components in the background thread. Perhaps it would help to [edit] your question with a more realistic example.

Comment: Ohh ok didn´t know this... Could you give me an example code? I only know how to override the onSucceeded method in the Task class, but i dont know how to call it on the controller class! Did you mean somthing like if(task.isSucceeded)-->create Button??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't create the UI in the background thread. There is (at best) very rarely a need to do this. If you need to perform some long-running task that retrieves data you need in order to create your UI, return the data from the task, and create the UI in the task's `onSucceeded` handler:

```
public class SomeControllerClass {

    @FXML
    private AnchorPane root ;

    public void initialize() {
        Task<SomeDataType> task = new MyTask();
        task.setOnSucceeded(e -> {
            // this method executed on FX Application thread.

            SomeDataType result = task.getValue();
            // now create UI and update root, using the data retrieved
        });
        Thread thread = new Thread(task);
        thread.start();
    }

}
```

and

```
public class MyTask extends Task<SomeDataType> {

    @Override
    public SomeDataType call() {

        SomeDataType result = longRunningProcess();
        return result ;
    }
}
```